# Get the data from WebView and display in activity Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, leaflet

I have a map made in web. I display it in the android app(Android Studio) using WebView. The map has a icon of pet store when I click  the icon the Petstore name pop up. How I can display the information of the PetStore from the webview to the android activity. Its like a profile of the PetStore but instead in the Web I want to display it on the App made in Android Studio. The Map I use is LeafLet esri in JS. The data is from Firestore database.

[image: This is the map I made in JS and the pop up Name]

This will be display in Android App using WebView, When I Click the VIEW PROFILE button I want the information displayed in the Android App activity. The database I use is Firestore

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried in code to achieve that?

Comment: @AlexMamo no, i dont have any idea how